# In Eclipse, how can i display WEB-INF as a flat view?

Tags: eclipse, package, flat, web-inf

I'm tired of drilling down into my jsp folder over and over, is there any way to make WEB-INF a flat package view in eclipse? I tried to change it in the view settings but it didn't seem to matter. I think I am using 3.6.

Edit - I have tried to use virtual folders as a shortcut to some of my popular folders, but unfortunately any changes made in virtual folders won't register a build when the server is running.

Comment: The WEB-INF folder is not a Java package... did you try working with filters?

Comment: I don't want to exclude anything, its just a pain to navigate nested jsp folders.

Comment: Ok, what we did in several projects is that we just named the folders according to Java packages, that way you can avoid nexted folders at all. E.g. create a folder in WEB-INF called `com.company.module.xyz.views`

Comment: I must be missing something, if I do that i still see those folders nested in a hierarchy, for instance I have to click + to expand com, then + to expand company. How did you make yours unnested?

Comment: Do just create one folder called `com.xyz`, not 2 folders `com` and `xyz`...

Comment: haha that is certainly bootleg, but it works. It just makes referencing jsp files in java very strange, ie: 'com.company.module/page.jsp' But I'll give you points for thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you really can't display it as a flat view. The flat stuff is contributed by JDT which does not understand what's happening in the WEB-INF folder. I suggest you file an enhancement request on Eclipse against the web tools project for this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your physical directory of your project and edit ***.classpath*** file(if its hidden make it visible)

Look at the src's structure in the classpathentry tag for the src folder copy and modify it to your folder, for example look at the modified the webapp folder

```
<classpathentry  kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/webapp">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Hope this helps